# How to prove convergence for multiplying sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For this question, I'm not sure how to do the proof. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let a, b ∈ R. Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$
converges to a and that $\{b_n\}$ converges to b. Moreover suppose that {bn} is bounded above by some c ∈ R
+. Provide a complete and accurate $\epsilon$ − N proof that $\{a_nb_n\}$

$\{a_n\}$ $\to$ a

$\{b_n\}$ $\to$ b

$b_n \le c$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, st if $n>N1$, $|a_n - a|<\epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, st if $n>N2$, $|b_n-b|<\epsilon$

N = max(N1,N2)

$|a_nb_n - ab|$

$ =|a_nb_n - a_nb + a_nb - ab|$

$= |a_n(b_n-b) + b(a_n-a)|$

$\le |a_n(b_n-b)| + |b(a_n-a)|$

$ = |a_n| |b_n-b| + b|a_n-a|$

$ < (a+\epsilon)\epsilon + b\epsilon$

$ = (a+b)\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality,

$$ |a_nb_n-ab| = |a_nb_n - a_nb +a_nb - ab| \leq |a_nb_n-a_nb| + |a_nb - ab| $$

Then

$$ |a_nb_n-a_nb| + |a_nb - ab| = |a_n||b_n-b|+|b||a_n-a| $$

Now $a_n$ is bounded since it's convergent, so suppose its bounded by $M$. Thus $|a_n|\leq M$.

Now we can make $|a_n-a|$ and $|b_n-b|$ arbitrarily small. So we make $|a_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2|b|}$ and $|b_n-b|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$. Then

$$ |a_nb_n-ab| \leq |a_n||b_n-b|+|b||a_n-a| < M\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2M} + |b|\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2|b|} = \varepsilon $$
which is the definition of convergence.

Comment: But how do we address the fact that $b_n$ is bounded? did you mean to say $b_n$ is bounded instead of $a_n$?

Comment: Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded because they are both convergent. Convergence of $b_n$ was invoked when setting $|b_n - b| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$.

Comment: But the question says suppose $b_n$ is bounded though?

Comment: Do you mean $b_n \le M$?

Comment: The proof works the same if you switch $a_n$ and $b_n$

Comment: Why did we pick $|a_n-a|$ to be less than epsilon over two times absolute value of b?

Comment: So that we have full control over the $|b||a_n-a|$ term at the end. $|b|$ could be huge so we cancel it out by letting $|a_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon} {2|b|}$ so that $|b||a_n-a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ at the end.

Comment: So if we switch $a_n$ and $b_n$, then what would it look like?

Comment: The exact same but with $a_n$ and $b_n$ switched.